# Syntax error while creating own function in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, function

I tried to create own function in MySQL, but the code below doesn't work. There is any syntax error, but after 30mins I'm unable to find what is wrong. Any ideas?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `gps_distance`;;
CREATE FUNCTION `gps_distance`(lat1 FLOAT,lng1 FLOAT,lat2 FLOAT,lng2 FLOAT) RETURNS float
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
SET lat1 = lat1 * pi() / 180;
SET lng1 = lng1 * pi() / 180;
SET lat2 = lat2 * pi() / 180;
SET lng2 = lng2 * pi() / 180;

    RETURN acos
    (   cos(lat1)*cos(lng1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lng2)
      + cos(lat1)*sin(lng1)*cos(lat2)*sin(lng2)
      + sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)
    ) * 6372.795;

END;;
```

The error is reported on line 6, after `BEGIN` clause.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Should it depends on MySQL version (I have 5.6.21)? On PMA version (4.3.0)? I tried to run this query from PHP script, the same problem.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: where is the `DELIMITER` ?

Comment: You didn't change the delimiter, so your `;` are terminating the function definition, before it ever really gets started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the delimiter is set to something other than semicolon

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `gps_distance`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `gps_distance`(lat1 FLOAT,lng1 FLOAT,lat2 FLOAT,lng2 FLOAT) RETURNS float
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
SET lat1 = lat1 * pi() / 180;
SET lng1 = lng1 * pi() / 180;
SET lat2 = lat2 * pi() / 180;
SET lng2 = lng2 * pi() / 180;

    RETURN acos
    (   cos(lat1)*cos(lng1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lng2)
      + cos(lat1)*sin(lng1)*cos(lat2)*sin(lng2)
      + sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)
    ) * 6372.795;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

add delimiter in procedure.

```
DELIMITER // 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `gps_distance`;
CREATE FUNCTION `gps_distance`(lat1 FLOAT,lng1 FLOAT,lat2 FLOAT,lng2 FLOAT) RETURNS float
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
SET lat1 = lat1 * pi() / 180;
SET lng1 = lng1 * pi() / 180;
SET lat2 = lat2 * pi() / 180;
SET lng2 = lng2 * pi() / 180;

    RETURN acos
    (   cos(lat1)*cos(lng1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lng2)
      + cos(lat1)*sin(lng1)*cos(lat2)*sin(lng2)
      + sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)
    ) * 6372.795;

END //

DELIMITER;
```